# Using logrotate to only compress and delete old files without rotating

Tags: logrotate

I want to compress some log files which have name format as abc.log.yyyy-MM-dd
and then delete the compressed log file (abc.log.yyyy-MM-dd.gz) after x days.I don't want logrotate to rotate files(i.e. create new files), I only want it to compress and delete the compressed files after x days.

I tried using this pattern to only compress files:

To Compress files:

```
/var/log/management/abc.log.*[!.gz]
su x y
daily
nocreate
missingok
compress
dateext
dateformat
rotate 6 #If I don't provide this parameter, files are deleted as soon as they 
          are compressed
} 

To delete compressed files after x days:
/var/log/management/abc.log.*.gz* {
su x y
daily
rotate x
maxage x
}
```

After 2 execution of logrotate, the result is as follows:

abc.log.2019-05-20.**gz.1.gz**

abc.log.2019-05-21.gz.1

abc.2019-05-22.gz

The compressed and rotated files is compressed again.

Can someone tell the exact regex pattern for filename that should be used

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
/var/log/management/abc.log.*[!.gz]
```

with

```
/var/log/management/abc.log.*[0-9]
```

Your combination of `dateext` with an empty `dateformat` is a nice way avoiding additional numbers in the filename!
When somebody else finds this answer, the next line is important:

```
nocreate
```

And when you want to delete these files after 60 days, use

```
postrotate
   find /var/log/management -name "abc.log.*gz" -type f -mtime +60 -exec rm -f {} \;
endscript
```